# Multiple withs syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
create table non_parents as
  with
    grandparents(grandfather, grandson) as (
      select a.parent, b.child from parents as a, parents as b
      where a.child = b.parent UNION
      select grandfather, child from grandparents, parents
      where grandson = parent
      ),
    greatparents(greatest, great) as (
      select grandfather, grandson from grandparents UNION
      select grandson, grandfather from grandparents
      )
  select greatest, great from greatparents, dogs d1, dogs d2
  where d1.name = greatest, d2.name = great
  order by d1.height - d2.height;
```

So I basically have one `parents(parent, child)` table and trying to get the pair of non-parent relationships.

I think I got multiple with syntax as 

`with tb1 as (), tb2 as ()
select * 
from ...
where...;`

But the output still runs syntax error `Error: near ",": syntax error`

And I've been staring at this code for a long time so can I please get some  tips on my syntax error?

Comment: @GordonLinoff There is no `WITH CLAUSE ` in **MySQL**.

Comment: Maybe replace `where d1.name = greatest, d2.name = great` with `where d1.name = greatest and d2.name = great` ?

Comment: How silly I was!!!! Thank you so much for saving me from this!!

Comment: I'm pretty new to sql, I'm curious is there a better way of debugging sql rather than staring at sometimes ambiguous error msg?

Comment: @jen007 . . . Start with a simple query and add one clause and condition at a time.

Comment: Thanks!! That's what I'm currently doing. I just found it somewhat cumbersome when the query gets complicated with recursions and subqueries.